# Delay post response in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I want to do some processing before sending the POST response. But from below code it's sending response without waiting for `var processedFile = process(writeToFile);` and it's processing the last line   `response.status(200).json({"file":file_name_output});`

Is there anyway to delay the response until the method `process(writeToFile);` gets completed

```
app.post('/data', function(request, response){
   // console.log("DATA::"+request.body.data);
    var html_data = request.body.data;
 // Get Random Number
    var random = randomIntFromInterval(1,999);
    //Input Html Location
     writeToFile = directory+random+'-input.html';

    //Output PDF Location
     file_name_output = random+'-output.pdf';
     file_name_output = directory+file_name_output;
     output = directory+random+'-output.pdf';

    // replace the images
    const $ = cheerio.load(html_data);

    $("img").filter(function(i,ele){

     var imageSource = $(ele).attr("src");

    // console.log(" Image["+i+"] Value::"+imageSource);

    if(i==0)
        {
     $(ele).attr("src","hellp.jpg");    
        }
    else
        $(ele).attr("src","home.jpg");  

   });

    //console.log(" Processed html :: "+$.html());


    fs.writeFile(writeToFile, $.html(), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
        var processedFile = process(writeToFile);
        //setTimeout(waitMethod, 3000);
       // var data =fs.readFileSync(processedFile);
       // response.contentType("application/pdf");
        //response.send(data);

        response.status(200).json({"file":file_name_output});

    }); 



}); // data
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `process` is an async function. In order to wait for it, you have to add an `async` and `await`:

```
    fs.writeFile(writeToFile, $.html(), async function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
        var processedFile = await process(writeToFile);

        response.status(200).json({"file":file_name_output});
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If i add the aysnc and await as above, it says that "Error on token async, ( expected after this token ". Any idea?

Comment: what node version do you have? (node -v)

Comment: It's v12.15.0 version

Comment: Can you check the code in https://esprima.org/demo/validate.html just to make sure?

Comment: Syntax is valid and i have checked in provided link